# Azure CLI - az storage blob delete-batch pattern

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli, azure-storage-account

I have a container called **container1** in my Storage Account **storageaccount1**, with the following files:

```
blobs/tt-aa-rr/data/0/2016/01/03/02/01/20.txt  
blobs/tt-aa-rr/data/0/2016/01/03/02/02/12.txt  
blobs/tt-aa-rr/data/0/2016/01/03/02/03/13.txt  

blobs/tt-aa-rr/data/0/2016/01/03/03/01/10.txt
```

I would like to delete the first 3, for that I use the following command:

`az storage blob delete-batch --source container1 --account-key XXX --account-name storageaccount1 --pattern 'blobs/tt-aa-rr/data/0/2016/01/03/02/*' --debug`

The files are not deleted and I see the following log:

```
urllib3.connectionpool : Starting new HTTPS connection (1): storageaccount1.blob.core.windows.net:443
urllib3.connectionpool : https://storageaccount1.blob.core.windows.net:443 "GET /container1?restype=container&comp=list HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

What is wrong with my pattern?

If I try to delete file by file it works.

Comment: try adding the .txt after the wildcard (*) so 'blobs/tt-aa-rr/data/0/2016/01/03/02/\*.txt'

Comment: @HugoBarona tried, does not help :(
also 'blobs/tt-aa-rr/data/0/2016/01/03/02/*/*.txt

Comment: @mibrl12 are the files located in subfolders under your container? If that is the case the pattern won't be able to pick up those.

Comment: @RoadRunner yes, in subfolders.

Than it is very sad..

Comment: oh sorry, i thought they were in the root folder. yes, that's true. Subfolders is not able to scan, only first level folders. You can reference here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-delete-batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comments, you are not able to apply patterns to subfolders, only first level folders, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-delete-batch.). But if you want, you can easily write a script to list the blobs in your container, using the prefix to filter them `az storage blob list` and then apply the delete for each of the result blobs.

Comment: Hm, did not see it in the docs explicitly stated about sub folders. However, it makes sense - azure charges for list :) thx!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what just worked for me — applied to the command you listed above.

```
az storage blob delete-batch --source container1 --account-key XXX --account-name storageaccount1 --pattern blobs/tt-aa-rr/data/0/2016/01/03/02/\* --debug
```

I didn't quote the `pattern` argument and I added an escape before the `*`. Using iTerm2 on a Mac. I didn't try `--debug` but the `--dryrun` argument was really helpful in getting it to tell me what it had matched (or not!).